# Using speakers on both screens depending on window location

Tags: audio, mac-mini, speakers, cinema-display

My configuration:

- 2x Apple Cinema Display 27"
- 1x late-2014 model Mac Mini

I would like the speakers in each display to be used depending upon which display the window that made the sound is on. For example if I had Youtube on the left screen I would want the video's soundtrack on that set of speakers, and if I have Slack on the right screen I would like it's notification sounds to come out of those speakers.

Is this possible? Presently I have to select one display to output all sounds from windows on either display.

Answer (score 1):

Rogue Amoeba make [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) [$29 USD plus any local tax] which can direct sound per app - though not per monitor, you'd have to set that up manually.

[image]